# Unterschied und Etymologie von faschistisch und faschistoid?

Tags: meaning, etymology, adjective, suffix

Wiktionary gibt faschistoid als

> dem Faschismus ähnlich, faschistische Eigenschaften aufweisend

aus. Also "ein bisschen/teilweise/leicht faschistisch"? Scheint mir ein sehr dehnbarer Begriff, bzw. je nach politischer Gesinnung und historischer Bildung empfindet es wohl der einzelne eher als Wertung denn als sachliche Beschreibung (faschistoid verstehe ich als z.B. Anführerkult aufweisend, glorifizierend, aber solche Merkmale des faschistischen Systems können ja auch in demokrat. Systemen vorkommen, Obama als Heilsbringer etc.). Umso misslungener empfinde ich faschistoid, da sich Faschismus ja gerade durch mehrere versch. Merkmale auszeichnet, das Adjektiv suggeriert aber eher etwas graduelles wie bei Farbübergängen, wie "ein bisschen braun in der Gesinnung".

Wo und wie (quantitative/qualitat. Bedeutung) wird der Begriff richtig benutzt; sollte er nur historisch verwendet werden, wenn man ihn überhaupt benutzen sollte/wollte? Empfindet Ottonormal überhaupt einen Unterschied zwischen faschistisch/faschistoid?

Leider gibt Wiktionary auch nicht aus, woher das Adjektiv kommt, das -oid Suffix ist auch eher rar im dt. Wortschatz. Wo kommt es her und was ist die ursprüngliche Bedeutung? Ich vermute mal Suffix in anderer Sprache) Bei den dt. [taucht es nicht auf](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix).

Comment: Otto Normal hat sowieso große Probleme damit, Faschismus zu erkennen – das ist ja gerade das Problem.

Comment: Unabhängig von Bildung und Gesinnung fassen viele Vieles als Wertung auf, wo sachliche Beschreibung gemeint ist.

Comment: Wen du irgendwas Soziales oder Geschichtswissenschaft machen willst, ist hier nicht das Forum. Ob "sich Faschismus ja gerade durch mehrere versch. Merkmale auszeichnet," macht es nicht zu einer Begriffsbestimmung sonder zu einer Definitionsfrage. faschistoid ersetzt im Sprachgebrauch dann teile des Begriffs, über den du versucht hast dich hinwegzudefinieren

Answer (score 4):

Der [Duden hilft](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/faschistoid), wie (fast) immer:

> zu Faschist und griechisch -oeidḗs = ähnlich

So ähnlich wie die Faschisten, faschistische Züge, in der Art der Faschisten.

Comment: man könnte also sagen, "faschistisch" verhalte sich zu "faschistoid" wie "gelb" zu "gelblich"...

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid) gibt als Herkunft von "humanoid" das Lateinische (homo) und das Griechische (εἶδος = „Gestalt“) an. Ich vermute ebenfalls, dass die Endung (in dieser Bedeutung) nur bei echten Fremdwörtern (wenn es sowas gibt) vorkommt. Zumindest fällt mir kein Gegenbeispiel ein.

Comment: +1 - zur griechischen Wurzel für das Suffix „-oid“ siehe auch den Eintrag bei [grammis](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/pls/public/gramwb.ansicht?v_app=g&v_kat=gramm&v_buchstabe=O&v_id=1908) und im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_oid).

Answer (score 3):

Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faschismus#Begriff) ist der Begriff "Faschismus" entweder beschränkt auf die Zeit um 1920-1945 und das damalige Regime in Italien oder auch noch auf die damaligen Regime in Deutschland und Japan.

Wenn etwas also "faschistoid" ist ('der Gestalt nach dem Faschismus gleicht'), dann ist es nicht 'leicht/ein bischen' faschistisch, sondern es ist 'wie' der Faschismus, aber zu anderen Zeiten oder an einem anderen Ort z.B. nicht in Deutschland um 1940, sondern vielleicht heutzutage.